# handling interruption in auxiliary clock

Tags: c, vxworks

I am having following code from big code base of an embedded application. I am trying to understand code and have following questions.

```
old_rate = sysAuxClkRateGet();
sysAuxClkRateSet(50);

sysAuxClkConnect ((FUNCPTR) scanDispatcher, 0);

/* Enable dispatcher */

sysAuxClkEnable ();
```

My questions are

1. Do scanDispatcher is called for each tick or after 50 ticks?
2. Is sysAuxClkRateSet(50); means we have 50 ticks per second? Is my understanding is right.

Comment: I think these questions would be better answered by the documentation for the libraries you're using. The `sysAuxClk` functions are not part of the C standard libraries.

Comment: Question is on Vxworks platform using API provided by VxWorks

Comment: the documentation should have better explanations. 50/s cannot be true, it's too slow. it's more convincing that 50/ms.

Answer (score 1):

The auxiliary clock ISR will call scanDispatcher (with argument 0) every time it's invoked to handle the auxilary clock interrupt.

sysAuxClkRateSet(50) defines the frequency of the auxiliary clock interrupt. Since the auxiliary clock driver ISR doesn't perform other actions than managing the timer device and calling the scanDispatcher routine, you can change the frequency.

There are two kind of limits in the frequency values you can use:

1. The auxiliary clock driver (part of the BSP you're using) defines absolute minimum and maximum values that the driver is able to manage
2. The real maximum limit is defined by the system load introduced by scanDispatcher and it's execution time; remember, in any case, that scanDispatcher is executed at interrupt time, so its' execution time should always be very short.

A last caveat: auxiliary clock isn't a mandatory device in VxWorks: most of the BSPs support an auxiliary clock device, but (in principle) you could find a BSP that doesn't support it.